# How to do a delay after every iteration in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to add a delay after every iteration in a foreach loop, so the *Treat* method gets called only every 2 seconds. I **do not** want to use `Thread.Sleep`because I want to still be able to use my program while the loop is running. I'm trying to tell the foreach loop to wait 2 seconds before doing the next iteration.
Here's what I have so far:

```
    public async void HandlingAsync(ListViewItem woodItem)
    {
        IList<ListViewItem> woodList = new List<ListViewItem>();
        woodList.Add(woodItem);
        foreach(ListViewItem Item in woodList)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Treat(Item);
        } 

    }

    public void Treat(ListViewItem woodItem)
    {
        woodItem.SubItems[3].Text = "dried";
        woodItem.SubItems[4].Text = "Ok";
    }
```

This doesn't work because the `await` command doesn't affect the foreach loop, only the commands inside of it. I can confirm that, because the ListView changes its items all at the same time, while it should change one item and wait 2 seconds before changing the next item.

**EDIT**: Marc Gravell ist right. The foreach loop absolutely respects the `await` command. So his answer works 100%. My problem was neither in the foreach loop nor in the `await` command. It didn't work because my *HandlingAsync* Method got called multiple times. This results in calling the *Treat* Method almost instantly muliple times. That means, that every woodItem got changed at the same time with a delay of 2 seconds. To solve this, the *HandlingAsync* should only be called *once*. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by _the await command doesn't affect the foreach loop_?  It's the asynchronous version of doing a `Thread.Sleep`.  What exact results are you getting from this that are not what you expect?

Comment: You could use `Thread.Sleep(2000);`

Comment: @L_J Not if the OP needs to not block the thread.

Comment: @juharr I want the Treat Method being called every 2 seconds, at the moment my program calls it immediately after every iteration.

Comment: @CaramelBailey's Immediately the first time?  If so just put the delay before the call.  Right now it should call it immediately the first time then wait 2 seconds before every call after that.

Comment: @juharr Putting it before the call doesn't work. The foreach loop doesn't get affected by await, so it continues doing its iterations.

Comment: "The foreach loop doesn't get affected by await," - yes it does; it really does; if something isn't working quite right, that's fine - but: `foreach` *absolutely* respects the `await` here

Comment: How exactly are you determining that the delay isn't occurring?

Comment: Provide a working repro and this question won't be closed, but at the moment evidence is pretty thin on the ground.

Comment: @juharr I have a Listview where every wood piece  from my itemList should be changed singly, but it changes them all at the same time.

Comment: Put `Application.DoEvents()` inside the loop. It's a razor and can cut sometimes but should help here.

Comment: to explain @WiktorZychla's point - it sounds like the issue here is that repaint is suspended during this loop. You can use `DoEvents` to force it, but ... that's pretty horrible in many ways, and any time you *can* avoid `DoEvents`, you *should* avoid `DoEvents`. Are you sure there isn't an explicit "disable paint" / "suppress changes" / etc call before your loop?

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code then because we have no idea how your method is interacting with your itemList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foreach` respects `await` just fine; here's an example in a console:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    string[] woodList = { "maple", "ash", "oak", "elm", "birch" };
    foreach (string wood in woodList)
    {
        Treat(wood);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}

private static void Treat(string wood)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: treating {wood}");
}
```

the output for me is (with obvious pauses):

```
28/08/2018 15:45:10: treating maple
28/08/2018 15:45:12: treating ash
28/08/2018 15:45:14: treating oak
28/08/2018 15:45:16: treating elm
28/08/2018 15:45:18: treating birch
```

So: if your code isn't behaving as expected - the problem isn't with the `foreach`/`await`. Can you perhaps show more of the surrounding context, and indicate what makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: I updated my question and added some code. My foreach loop continues without waiting 2 seconds. I can see that, because my ListView changes all its items a the same time.

Comment: @CaramelBailey's hence my question in the comments about whether there's some code that is suppressing UI updates